# How to do CSS3 boxshadow on 2 sides of a div?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this simple code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kerp3/

The box has an inner box shadow o all 4 sides. I need the box shadow to only appear on the left and bottom sides.

How to change this code:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 9px 0 #000;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help, this should work cross browser.

```
.shadow {

    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');

}
```

Here is the original author : 
http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

```
.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
}
```

See this page:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

With a small change to the color and the offsets it becomes fairly simple:

```
div { width: 300px; height: 300px; 

   box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px -3px #666;

}
```

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kerp3/3/) of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using negative values like so:

```
div { width: 300px; height: 300px;
    /* Try this. */
    box-shadow: inset 4px -4px 7px -4px #000; 
}
```

The first 4px pushes the shadow box to the left by 4px, hiding what you would normally see on the right, if you left it at 0.

The second -4px value pushes the shadow vertically down, again hiding the top shadow.

The higher 7px blur value gives me a more than a I need, but if I add a spread of -4px, that extra blur will be clipped. Leaving only a soft grey shadow edge, instead of the hard black one you'll usually see.

See my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/vVUB5/

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a shadow only to certain sides of a `<div>`, but you can adjust the X and Y offsets so that the shadow gets clipped on the sides where you don't want it.

This gave me the effect you're looking for in Safari:

`box-shadow: 7px -7px 9px #000 inset;`